# How to iterate map inside a map

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

Hi I have a map which has a map inside a map as below

```
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> finaldataelementmap=New Map<String,Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String,String> tempmap = new Map<String,String>();
    finaldataelementmap.put(Id, tempmap);

   // The tempmap has the list of values as below
 //   (AcccountId = xxxx, Amount = xxxx, Tracking = xxxx, Mode = xxxx, Value = xxxx)
```

Now I want to iterate over finaldataelement map and get accountid, amount,tracking, mode values to store in different variables.

My updated code based on the suggestion below

```
List<Invoice__c> invlst = [select id,Account__c from Invoice__c where Account__c IN :mapAccount.keyset()];            
                      List<OrderApi__Invoice__c > invids = new List<Invoice__c>();           
                        system.debug('Before final opp' +finaldataelementmap);
system.debug('Final is' +finaldataelementmap.keySet());
                        if(invlst.size()>0){
                             for(Invoice__c inv : invlst){
                            for (String s : finaldataelementmap.keySet()) {

              Map<String, String> innerMap = finaldataelementmap.get(s);
    system.debug('Inner map is ' +innerMap);
                                     Receipt__c rc = new Receipt__c();

    rc.Amount = innermap.get('Amount');
                                        rc.Type__c = innermap.get('Mode');
```

When I print the finaldataelementmap, it gives me two key value pair sets
1. key 500 , value - list as above
2. key 650 , value - **gives the value as "Already Output instead of printing values**

```
 19:21:04.809 (3450018573)|USER_DEBUG|[472]|DEBUG|Before final oop {629={Amount=5100.0000, Type=, Mode=Check, ...}, 630=(already output)}

19:21:04.809 (3450286435)|USER_DEBUG|[474]|DEBUG|Final is {Amount=5100.0000, Type=,Mode=Check, ...}

19:21:04.809 (3450413947)|USER_DEBUG|[476]|DEBUG|Innermap is {Amount=5100.0000,Type=,Mode=Check, ...}
19:21:04.809 (3451144354)|USER_DEBUG|[481]|DEBUG|Amount is 5100.00
19:21:04.809 (3451208808)|USER_DEBUG|[482]|DEBUG|tracking isC10426
19:21:04.809 (3452343632)|USER_DEBUG|[481]|DEBUG|Amount is 5100.00
19:21:04.809 (3452372836)|USER_DEBUG|[482]|DEBUG|tracking isC10426
19:21:04.809 (3452771535)|USER_DEBUG|[526]|DEBUG|Size of receipts is2
19:21:04.809 (3452343632)|USER_DEBUG|[481]|DEBUG|Amount is 5100.00
19:21:04.809 (3452372836)|USER_DEBUG|[482]|DEBUG|tracking isC10426
19:21:04.809 (3452771535)|USER_DEBUG|[526]|DEBUG|Size of receipts is4
19:21:04.809 (3452343632)|USER_DEBUG|[481]|DEBUG|Amount is 5100.00
19:21:04.809 (3452372836)|USER_DEBUG|[482]|DEBUG|tracking isC10426
19:21:04.809 (3452771535)|USER_DEBUG|[526]|DEBUG|Size of receipts is6
```

Now, Instead of iterating over values of both 629 and 630 , which has two different amounts, the loop is iterating over only key 629, multiple times. I suppose this is because when I print the finaldataelementmap, I see that the value for 630 is listed as "already output" instead of actual value

Comment: What specific issue did you encounter? Did you receive an error message? What is the rest of your code inside the `for` loop? (Please [edit] to add information).

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 3):

You don't need nested iteration here. There's no reason to iterate over the keys of the inner `Map`. While you could make that work, you'd end up with a complex `if`/`else` or `switch on` statement inside the inner `for` loop.

It's much easier to directly access the inner `Map` keys whose values you require. It'd look something like this:

```
for (String s : finaldataelementmap.keySet()) {
    Map<String, String> innerMap = finaldataelementmap.get(s);

    Receipt__c r = new Receipt__c();
    r.Amount__c = innerMap.get('Amount');
    r.Tracking__c = innerMap.get('Tracking');
    // and so on. 
}
```

#### Second Problem

Your `Map` `finaldataelementmap` contains two references to the same child `Map` under different keys. The code creating that `Map` has a bug in it - usually, this happens when you forget to create a new object instance in each iteration of a loop that's generating a nested data structure.

Comment: I did try that but I am having the same issue. Added the log for finaldataelementmap in the question above

Comment: I'm sorry, @user64977, but I really have no idea what you're asking. You're showing debug output, but there are no debug statements in the code you've shown. **What, specifically, does not work? What is the behavior? What error do you see?**

Comment: I did add the debug statements in the code and the complete statement. I am getting the "already output" in the map value instead of actual values.